# Increasing Disk Size of provisioned GCP Cloud Shell VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am looking to increase the disk size for the 5GB persistent disk that Google provides for Cloud Shell.

I have read all the docs but, they only mention EC2 machines. Though, the Cloud Shell is also an EC2 machine when i loom at the VM's the Cloud Shell machi e is not listed.

PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the size of the Cloud Shell disk. Cloud Shell runs on a Compute Engine instance that Google controls and is not a resource in your project. Cloud Shell is a container and you can deploy your own container on Compute Engine COS or via Docker.

Comment: I now realized. I created a Compute instance, now i am having the issue where i cant change the explorer in the cloudshell editor to show the file system of that Compute instance. I also tried using a COS image but from there i can't get anything installed , there is no apt-get, no npm nothing. Just diskspace.

Comment: COS is designed to be locked down for containers. A container normally cannot access the host file system except thru volume mounts. Your original question has been answered. Check this answer and open a new question if you have another question.